# Clarification on the proof $A_n$ is simple

Tags: abstract-algebra

In Lang's Algebra book theorem 5.5 (which can be found here https://math24.files.wordpress.com/2013/02/algebra-serge-lang.pdf on page 33), I don't quite understand the last paragraph. When the author said $\sigma$ move $r,s$ other than $i,j,k$, does it mean that $\sigma$ contains the cycle $(i,j,k,r,s)$? If not, then how come $\sigma'(i) = i$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't quite mean that $\sigma$ contains the cycle $[ijkrs]$. It just means that $r$ and $s$ are also not fixed points of $\sigma$.  So the assumption is limited to $\sigma(i) = j$, $\sigma(j) = k$, $\sigma(r) \ne r$, and $\sigma(s) \ne s$ (with all $i,j,k,r,s$ distinct).  That can happen in one of several ways: it might be that $\sigma$ contains the cycle $[ijkrs]$, or it might mean $\sigma$ contains $[ijkr]$ and some other cycle permuting $s$, or it might be $\sigma$ contains $[ijk]$ and other cycle(s) permuting $r$ and $s$.

In any case, $\sigma'(j) = \tau(\sigma(\tau^{-1}(\sigma^{-1}(j))) = j$ so $j$ is a fixed point of $\sigma'$.  I'm not sure if I'm using the same multiplication convention (left-to-right vs right-to-left) as the text, so that might be why I have $j$ instead of $i$, but the argument is extremely similar no matter which convention one uses.  The key is that as long as there are two elements other than $i,j$ to work with, you can use those to form a $3$-cycle that induces an extra fixed-point after combining it with $\sigma$.

EDIT: One important detail that is understated by the text is that we must be sure that $\sigma$ and $\tau$ do not commute (else $\sigma’$ is the identity so its fixed points don’t cause a contradiction).  This can happen if we are careless with our choice of $r,s$, for instance if $\sigma$ is the $9$-cycle $[ij \,k \,xy \,r \,zw \,s]$.  However, it is easy to check that we can choose $r,s$ differently to fix this (in the case that $\sigma$ has such a large cycle, we could just pick the two elements after $k$).